Road Tyre on Gravel Bike Compaitability
I use a gravel bike as a daily ride (Jamis Renegade), fitted out as stock with:
Wheels:

WTB ST i23 TCS 2.0 (UST Tubeless Compliant System) disc rims,
32H, Joytec alloy 6-bolt hubs, 14g stainless steel spokes and front
12mm/rear 12×142 thru-axle with Switch Lever

Tires:

WTB Riddler Comp 700CX37C, 30tpi Casing, Wire Bead (48-61) WTB BYWAY 650CX40C, 30tpi
Casing, Wire Bead (44)

I've recently signed up for a charity road race, and thought about getting some faster road tyres. But I have no idea about to decide what tyres to run and what size.
I use to run Schwalbe Marathon Plus on a different bike. Can I run something like a  700x25c Marathon Plus? if not, how do I determine compatibility?

You will be doing yourself a disservice with 25C tyres. Even professional racers use 28C normally and up to 32C for rough stages (pavé, gravel). See also https://youtube.com/watch?v=AK5KLvrzrb4&pp=ygUOZ2NuIHR5cmUgd2lkdGg%3D where 35C can be as fast as 26C. A fast road tyre at 32C is a much better choice for a normal person, 25C only for those with narrow rim brakes.

I have 2 very similar wheelsets for my gravel bike, one with road tyres (32mm Schwalbe Marathon Supreme / Schwalbe One Plus) and one with the same Riddlers you've got.
I also have plenty of experience with Marathon Plus for commuting.
You absolutely could do this, but I wouldn't.  Riddler 37s are faster and more comfortable than Marathon Plus 32s.  I'll happily ride 200km of mainly road on the Riddlers because of a few off-road stretches, just reducing the tyre pressure if it gets really rough.
If you're going to put a different tyre on for the road ride, use something more appropriate.  You can still have decent puncture protection on the tread, but Marathon Plus have tough sidewalls. That means they're stiff, and stiff sidewalls slow you down.  I like my Marathon Plus, but for commuting and other times when predictability is more important than speed

A few thoughts, that are a bit too long to be comments:

if the question is only about size, the link provided by @mattnz will provide the answer. There's however an inconsistency in the question for the tire size, as you mention two different bead diameters (riddler: 700c/28", byway: 650b/27.5"). The bead diameters must match of the rim and the tire, so if you have 27.5" rims, you need to fit tires designed for this size).
rolling resistance is a complex topic, the tread pattern is only one component, the pressure, the carcass structure, the compound and the kind of tube (or lack of tube) also matter. According to https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com, the "performance" version of the Riddler is an average gravel tire (reference rolling resistance: 22.8W@2.8bars, but the 30TPI casing suggests an entry level version of the tire, that should perform less well, but hasn't been measured on this site), the Marathon Plus is not known for its low rolling resistance (for the 37mm, 25.5W@4bars). Marathon plus are the best performers when it comes to puncture resistance, but it comes at a cost (rolling resistance, weight and discomfort).
at reasonable pressures, the section has a limited impact on rolling resistance, but a big one on comfort (for mid-range tires and up), thinner tires can achieve lower resistance because they can reach very high pressures, but that doesn't mean you'd like to ride at those pressure, but wider tires can achieve similar rolling resistance at lower pressures (only true for supple tires).
supple gravel tires with shallow thread can roll well enough on roads. They may not reach the absolute performance of road tires, but they can reach a level where improvements mostly matter in competitive rides.

So in short, if you want to improve rolling resistance, going to mid-range 40mm gravel tires will be a step up. You can also go to "real" supple road tires, but it doesn't make sense to go as thin as 25mm, you can go to 32mm or wider (wider road tires are niche products however, so will be in the high range in terms of price).
Note that if you want to prioritise puncture protection, BRR has an article over a size comparison for the Marathon Plus. The 25mm version is not tested, but the 32mm performs less well than 37mm (different compound) - the 37mm has the lowest rolling resistance among the ones that have been tested.

An interesting detail is that BRR has two comparisons for same tire at different sizes. The other one, https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/specials/grand-prix-5000-comparison, comes to conclusion that at recommeded pressure, narrower is very slightly faster and at similar comfort level the differences are barely measurable.

@ojs it should be pointed out that the BRR definition of comfort is "4.5mm tire drop", then resistance is measured on the same steel roller. When I think comfort, I think more about non-smooth surfaces (bad asphalt of cobblestones included). A wider tire with a lower pressure will "bounce" less, which will translate into a higher speed even if rolling resistance remains the same. (I would also add: if the casing/compound is the same, for the Marathon, it's not true for example). But it's an interesting data point nonetheless.

I would be interested in actual reproducible measurements for the bounce losses. At least least it would be intellectually honest to format it more as "there are no measurable differences but i know wider tires are faster and look at the professionals"

@ojs there's this article from Silca https://silca.cc/blogs/silca/part-4b-rolling-resistance-and-impedance that compares rolling resistance on different roughness. Note that they only look at pressure with the same width, but if rolling resistance is indeed mostly dependent of the casing and compound, wider tires have the same rolling resistance at lower pressure, so can be faster on rougher surfaces (but then there's the catch of aero). But I consider the benefit of wider tires on rougher surfaces to be proven (the evolution of MTBs and gravel bikes is a good illustration).

Thanks, looks like someone finally did serious measurements for the idea. I still doubt that wide tires are significantly better, because they are harder at equal pressure, so narrower tire at the same pressure dampens vibrations more. The data still looks like lowering pressure indefinitely doesn't improve rolling resistance on normal surfaces so the ability to run wide tires at very low pressure wouldn't help.

@ojs I personally don’t buy wide tires to run them at the same pressure, but to (be able to) run them at lower pressures. There are of course drawbacks to low pressures: rolling resistance on smooth surfaces, damaging rims (or pinch flats), wobbliness. You can mitigate that with width, but then you have other drawbacks: aero (frontal and rim interface), weight. So as usual, there’s an optimum to find. Personal example: I have 42mm on my gravel bike, I run them at 3.2 bars for club road rides, and 2 bars for the rougher gravel. Note that perfect tarmac is rare here on the secondary network.

Frame clearance is only one of the components to keep in mind in your case. Since you are already moving from a wide clearance (at least 37mm) you won't have trouble for road tire clearance.
You do have 2 other chalages;

Inner rim width; which seems to be 21mm. There are charts like this to tell you which rim width will work. In this case 25c seems just fine.
You seem to have two different sized rims; 700c and 650c. The 700x25c won't fit the 650c rim.

I have never seen 650c and from what I read you'll have a hard time finding a road tire for that rim.
So what do you need to determine compatibility:

Size with one 700c (could also be denoted as 622mm) and one 650c (could be denoted as 571mm)
Inner rim width compatibility with 21mm
Tire width theoretically but with at least room for 37c I doubt that will be a problem.

Footnote: the marathon plus is definitely not a fast road tire and 25c is very narrow. Your best bet is probably finding something which fits the 650c rim with a width between 30 and 35c.
